Should I cash out this annuity?
Here’s my situation. I’m 60 and retired for 3 years due to health issues. Im on SSD getting $2600 a month. My wife still works and has no intention of retiring. She makes around $125k. When I retired I had $90k in my 401k that I transferred to an annuity that I have yet to turn on. I’ve had it for two years. The issue is we have $55k in credit card and other debt. I feel like this $90k isn’t going to change our life and we ought to just bite the bullet, pay all the penalties and taxes and pay off all these cards. By doing this we save over $1500 a month, she can increase her 401k contribution and if we’re disciplined we can save some serious money quickly. Thoughts?

Your first priority  after survival should be getting rid of that credit card debt, since the interest rate on that is undoubtedly obscene. After that, you can consider investing, on whatever time scale.

How about bankruptcy? Retirement accounts are protected from bankruptcy.

Did I understand correctly that there's only $1500 per month going towards this debt?

@littleadv I thought annuities aren't considered a retirement account--so how would a bankruptcy help?

They are, but they are not covered by ERISA, so bankruptcy protection depends on State laws. 401k would be much much better. In any case, bankruptcy can help with taxes as well. Worth talking to a bankruptcy attorney.
